# Notify about changed variable in socket thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, thread-safety, unity-game-engine

I have Unity app which works as a socket server:

```csh
public class Server : MonoBehaviour
{
    private String outData;
    private String inData;

    public void writeData(String data){
        outData = data;
    }

    void Start()
    {       
        ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(dataHandler);
        mThread = new Thread(ts);
        mThread.Start();
    }

    void dataHandler()
    {
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(PORT);
        listener.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            var client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            new Thread(() =>
            {
                using (client)
                {
                    var reader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
                    var writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
                    while (true)
                    {
                        inData = reader.ReadLine();

                        if(outData != null){
                            writer.WriteLine(outData);
                            writer.Flush();
                            outData = null;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).Start();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not familiar with .NET threading and can't figure out how to make send data. When data comes socket thread wakes up and inData field updates. But when I call writeData nothing happens. Socket thread continue to sleep until inData updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > But when I call writeData nothing happens. Socket thread continue to sleep until inData updates.

That's because your thread is blocking on `inData = reader.ReadLine();`. It will sit there until it receives data (or an exception is thrown). Only then will it actually check for outgoing data and send it.

Reading data should be left in a separate thread like you have, but there is no need to send data in your thread. Sending data is not a blocking call. Your data will get pushed to some local buffer, and at some point in the future, the OS will take care of the rest. Your write method should look more like:

```
public void writeData(String data)
{
    foreach(StreamWriter clientWriter in ClientWriters)
    {
        clientWriter.WriteLine(outData);
        clientWriter.Flush();
    }
}
```

Where ClientWriters is a List that should be maintained on connect/disconnect. There are other ways to write this method, but basically, you need to send your outgoing data right away.